# Software access to smartphone autofocus

Tags: android, android-hardware

Is it possible to programmatically, even using root-access, to access the infrared laser autofocus of a smartphone, for programmatically controlling autofocus - turning on, off, changing the radiation power? In which direction to look? Are there any solutions from the Google company itself, in the source, through the API?